# Set a variable of superclass while testing subclass in Junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, inheritance, junit, subclass

I have a class A and a class B which extends class A

```
class A{
    protected String x = "";
    Method (){
    x = "val";
    }
}
class B extends A{
     // Uses x in a method
}
```

If I write Junit test case for a method in class B, I get value of x as an empty string "" as set while declaration. Is there a way to set the value for x to "val" while testing class B method?

Comment: You do that by creating a proper `B` instance. It is the child class, so it is also responsible for settings values to parent class variables when it needs individual values.

Comment: Hi @Tom, thanks for your comment. I've edited the question a bit. Can you suggest how can I set value in test case according to this

Comment: It looks like there is a small misconception here. You first need to design or implement class B to do whatever it needs to do to work correctly. If it needs to work with `Method` or `x`, then it needs to access them appropriately. Then a unit test can test the public and protected methods of `B` to verify they work as expected. So when your test has `x` as empty String instead of "val", then the issue is `B`, not your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the new scope of the question, you should be able to set x by creating an object of type B (bObject) then calling Method() from A.

> B bObject = new B();
> bObject.Method();

This would set X given the methodology you show in your question. You could also say

> B bObject = new B();
> bObject.setX(str);

Where str represents whatever you want x to be for your test case. This assumes you have x set up with a getter and setter in A, which is generally best practice.

Comment: Thanks for posting a very clear answer but I've edited my question a bit. How can I make it work if x is set using a method in class A